# How to find most cited researchers in a specific field?

Tags: journals, paper-submission

I need to send these items to a high-impact journal. However, I don't exactly know where I can find these pieces of information.

> The names, affiliations, h-index from either Web of Science or Google
> Scholar Citations, and full contact information including email
> addresses of six to ten leading researchers as determined by
> publication of important journal articles in the subject area of the
> paper outside of your circle/region as a Word file. They should not be
> your advisor, advisee, research sponsor, research collaborator, or
> someone with a conflict of interest. They can include senior
> researchers cited in your paper. Please disclose potential conflicts
> of interest if any.
>
> Who are the top 10 researchers in the world in the subject of the
> paper as determined by publication of impactful journal articles in
> the subject area of the paper? Please provide their name, affiliation,
> email address, and h-index from either Web of Science or Google
> Scholar Citations as a Word file. This will indicate whether the
> authors are familiar with the latest development in the field and
> their paper extends the state-of-the-art.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this (sort of) with Web of Science. Put in your search term, then check the Authors tab on the left. It gives you the names of the people with most publications matching that search term. To translate that to most cited, you'll have to check them one-by-one.

[image]

Comment: Apparently "Web of Science" link is no longer available: "Why can't I access Web of Science?" https://massey.libanswers.com/faq/272745#:~:text=The%20Library%20has%20not%20been,2023%2C%20including%20Web%20of%20Science.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance only at Massey University and a few others? It should work fine elsewhere (I just used it today).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the most highly cited researcher in the field of "optimization", then you can search `label: optimization` in Google Scholar and you'll get the following results:

[image]

For a different field, just change `optimization` to the field of your interest.